# Change index and titles font in Tufte style book

Tags: fonts, tufte

I want to change the index, titles and subtitles font in my document but I have no idea how to (I'm pretty new to Latex). I've searched for solutions to this problem without success. I am particularly using the Tufte style book, could someone please lend me a hand? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the font on the title page using

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}{%
  \begingroup%
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

  {\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont{\@author}\par}

  \vspace{4cm}
  {\fontsize{54}{54}\selectfont\textit\@title\par}

  \vspace{1.5cm}{\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\textsf{\@date}\par}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

The `tufte-book` class uses the `titlesec` package to change the heading style.
You can change the index style by changing the chapter style using something like

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
```

The same is possible for sections and subsections.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, justified]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title[Book Title]{Book Title \\ {\Huge\normalfont\bfseries Subtitle}}
\author{Author}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\titleformat{\section}{\huge\sffamily}{\thesection}{0pt}{\huge\sffamily}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\itshape}{\thesubsection}{0pt}{\Large\itshape}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}{%
  \begingroup%
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

  {\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont{\@author}\par}

  \vspace{4cm}
  {\fontsize{54}{54}\selectfont\textit\@title\par}

  \vspace{1.5cm}
  {\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\textsf{\@date}\par}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
  \section{First Section}
    \subsection{First Subsection}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
  \section{Section Section}
    \subsection{First Subsection}
    \subsection{Second Subsection}

\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I thank you so much, that works well. Is it possible to do something similar to change the page header font?  chapter titles appear in my page headers, can I change those typefaces as well?

Comment: You can do that by adjusting the settings of the [`fancyhdr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package that `tufte-book` uses internally. There is also a great documentation on [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Headers_and_footers#Style_customization_in_double-sided_documents).